# Determing if $f(x,y)$ is continuous at $(0,0)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I would really appreciate if someone could help me figure out where to start on this problem.

The question is to determine if $f$ is continuous at the origin.

$$\begin{equation}
  f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
    \dfrac{\sin(x-y)}{|x| + |y|}, & \text{if $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$}.\\
    0, & (x,y) = (0,0).
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
$$

I'm really struggling with these concepts and would appreciate if someone could help me out

Comment: Indeed, just set $y=0$ and look at the limit as $x \to 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A necessary condition for that function to be continuous at the origin is that the limit of the function along *any path* to the origin must equal $f(0,0) = 0$.

See what happens if you approach along an axis.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to vote this up but thank you

Comment: @manny, I'm glad I could help!  For now, I believe you are allowed to "accept" the most helpful answer (by clicking the green arrow).  This is good practice on Math:SE, and it lets future users know your question has been answered.

Comment: Okay! Actually @Kaj Hansen, can you please help me understand Surb's solution if you have the time? I don't understand why Surb chose to drop the absolute value bars and why the one-sided limits are different.

Comment: @manny, sure thing.  In his original response, he dropped the absolute values because he is approaching $0$ from the positive side.  So when $x>0$, $|x| = x$.  From there, the limit can be evaluated using L'Hopital's rule.  Next, if we consider $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^-} \frac{\sin(x)}{|x|}$, then note it is the same as $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+}\frac{\sin(-x)}{x}$.  If you again apply L'Hopital's rule to this, you'll find that it comes out to $-1$.

Answer (score 2):

You can use L'hopital's rule to show that $\lim_{x-y \to 0} \sin(x-y)/(x-y) = 1$. Thus your limit is equivalent to $\lim_{x,y \to 0} \frac{x-y}{|x| + |y|}$. If you consider any line $y = ax$ and take the limit as $x \to 0$, you will get that the limit is not $0$. So the function is not continuous at $0$.

Comment: Thank you! Your approach is very interesting. In the future, how would I know to try something like that? @user2566092

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x,0) = \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1 \neq 0=f(0,0)$$
It follows that $f$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$.

Comment: Actually $\lim_{x\to 0-}\frac{\sin x}{|x|}=-1.$

Comment: @mfl Right... I edited.

Comment: When you did the two sided limit, why did you drop the absolute value bars? I just don't understand why the one-sided limits are different. Thank you so much for your response though @Surb

Comment: @manny It is not a two sided limit (but it is enough to show that one side already don't works). Here $x$ is approached $0$ by the right, i.e. $x > 0$ and $x \to 0$. Maybe you are more used to this notation: $\lim_{x \underset{>}{\to} 0} f(x,0)$.